How to stop Windows Terminal from displaying spaces after characters in NFD form?
I am connected from Windows to macOS Sonoma via SSH, the path /Volumes/smbshare is an SMB-mounted share (on a Linux host). LANG is set to ja_JP.UTF-8:

This is what I see in the Windows Terminal (1.20.11781.0) when I create files containing German umlauts or Japanese compound characters:

And this is what I see in the Tabby Terminal in the same directory:

I am aware about the two normalization forms NFC and NFD and macOS using the latter.
I confirmed the results from both terminal applications are NFD-encoded by copying to the clipboard and checking with Python's unicodedata.is_normalized('NFD', ...).
The problem of additional space characters is:

happening for the files stored on the local APFS drive if they were copied from the SMB share (so the encoding is retained)
not happening for the files stored on the local APFS drive if I create them using the above same touch and ls. In that case the results are in the NFC form and printed properly in the Windows Terminal.

In other words, on the below diagram:

the red line is an NFD-encoded text badly rendered by the Windows Terminal
the bright green line is the text in the NFC form, rendered properly by the Windows Terminal
the dark green line is the text in the NFD form, rendered properly by the Tabby Terminal


Question 1 - fixing the red path, so it works like the dark green one
Can I fix the displaying of strings in the NFD form in the Windows Terminal?
Question 2 - fixing the red path so it works like the bright green one
Why is NFD applied only to the files stored on the SMB-mounted share?
Is it possible to change it to work like with a local filesystem?
Or is anything like a normalization to NFC (of any sent text) possible on-the-fly in SSH to avoid such problems?

Are you assuming this is a configuration issue? It actually sounds to me like it's an implementation issue – i.e. could be that your version of Windows Terminal doesn't implement combining characters correctly and "fixing" it would involve actual code changes to WT. (There are a few issues on GitHub already open about this...)

I don't know. Probably there are both: a problem in Windows Terminal and the way SMB is configured on macOS (although I could not find any options related to Unicode), as the behavior is different with local filesystem. I decided to ask here first to gain some grasp of what is going on. I would appreciate any advice. Searching Windows Terminal repository for is:issue NFD returns 0 results. is:issue macOS does not yield anything related either.

There's no specific encoding called "NFD" – what the normalization algorithm produces is a series of regular combining characters, so I suspect https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/pull/16916 might be related.

Ok, then not "NFD encoding," but "NFD form." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence#Normal_forms
